# React Native Paper align card content horizontal and vertical

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have had a couple of problems with this React Native Paper card, I need to vertically align the tittle but `justifyContent` is being pretty much ingnored.
Here's the [Card](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/card.html) I have been working on.

```js
const UnitCard = (props) => {
  return (
    <Card style={styles.card}>
      <Card.Content style={styles.cardContent}>
        <Title>UNIT CARD</Title>
        <Headline>Mt</Headline>
      </Card.Content>
    </Card>
  );
};
```

And this is the StyleSheet, I already tried ussing both `justifyContent` and `allignItems` as suggested [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/325)

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  card: {
    backgroundColor: "skyblue",
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    flex: 1,
  },
  cardContent: {
    backgroundColor: "coral",
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row"
  },
});
```

Here's a screenshot of my device

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I am new to React-Native but something like this helped me out.

What I did is I took a **Card** made it a circle and inside its **Card.Content** I made it take all the space of the **Card** and also made it circle and after that I wrote the properties to place all the views to be in centre of the **Card.Content** section.

```
<Card style={styles.cardCircle}>
  <Card.Content style={styles.cardCircleContent}>
      <Text>{"here"}</Text>
  </Card.Content>
</Card>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  cardCircle: {
    borderRadius: 100,
    width: 140,
    height: 140,
    backgroundColor: "red",
    elevation: 10,
  },
  cardCircleContent: {
    flex: 1,
    borderRadius: 100,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
});
```

Comment: I know its a late answer but hope it helps someone else